# Is it possible to connect HADOOP from non HDFS filesystem HBASE?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hbase

Configuration of hbase-site.xml @HBase

```html
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///D:/LocalData/HBASEDATA/</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking about HBase running in [standalone mode](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBase use Hadoop to leverage distributed file system and robust fault tolerant nature. If you are planning for non HDFS filesystem for Hbase, it will still work. You would not be able to get above advantages of HDFS and then there is no point in connecting to Hadoop, if you do not want to use HDFS.

I would suggest to use HDFS filesystem, if your data spans more than single machine. You can then set above property with hdfs path.

hdfs://nn:port/hbase